# Dynamically filter the date by 6 months from today

Tags: looker-studio

I basically want to be able to dynamically filter out my chart to display data for the last 6 months. For example, it would show Jan 2019 to June 2019 and in July it would show between Feb 2019 to July 2019

Presently, I'm using filters. I was thinking of creating a calculated field for the 6 months but there are no functions to help me play with dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the date-picker options, choose the one at the very bottom of the list which is called Advanced. Click on the end date option and where it says 'fixed' click and choose today. Do the same for the start date and you get the option to enter your conditions, which in this case would be today minus 6 months